# How to properly render an ' if ' condition with choices in HTML, Django

Tags: html, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

Hello I have a post model with visibility choices, I want only the post with public visibility to be shown in the homepage, but I tried to call the object in different ways but it isn't working. Please do have a look at the code

models

```
PUBLIC = 'PU'
PRIVATE = 'PR'
ONLY_ME = 'ME'
POST_VISIBILITY = (('PUBLIC', 'Public'), ('PRIVATE', 'Private'), ('ONLY_ME', 'Only me'))

class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.TextField(max_length=5000, blank=False, null=False)
    post_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, verbose_name="Date Posted")
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, verbose_name="Date Updated")
    likes = models.ManyToManyField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name='post_likes', blank=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    slug = models.SlugField(blank=True, unique=True, max_length=255)
    visibility = models.CharField(choices=POST_VISIBILITY, max_length=10, default=PUBLIC)
```

homepage

```
{% for post in posts %}
    {% if post.visibility == 'PUBLIC' %} <!--This seems to have a problem -->
```

I want only the public posts to be shown in the homepage, even though the post has been given visibility as public through admin panel, no posts are showing in the homepage. Please do let me know how can I use this condition with various choices.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Shouldn't the value of `PUBLIC` be `'PUBLIC'` instead of `'PU'`?

Comment: I tried with 'PU' too, but it doesn't show any posts.

Comment: can you please add the corresponding View.

Comment: Yes. i added that

Comment: is there any Posts in your DB.

Comment: yes i have! with visibility public

Comment: then it should, work fine, do you have any error?

Comment: Yes that worked. I had to change this too..
{% if post.visibility == 'PU' %}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this!

```
PUBLIC = 'PU'
PRIVATE = 'PR'
ONLY_ME = 'ME'
POST_VISIBILITY = [(PUBLIC, 'Public'), (PRIVATE, 'Private'), (ONLY_ME, 'Only me')]

class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.TextField(max_length=5000, blank=False, null=False)
    post_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, verbose_name="Date Posted")
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, verbose_name="Date Updated")
    likes = models.ManyToManyField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name='post_likes', blank=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    slug = models.SlugField(blank=True, unique=True, max_length=255)
    visibility = models.CharField(choices=POST_VISIBILITY, max_length=10, default=PUBLIC)
```

I guess the major problem was "post.visibility == 'PUBLIC'"

```
{% if post.visibility == 'PU' %}
```

In case you want more info about this, visit https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/fields/#choices